# NativeScript : Correct way to override the protoype native proxy methods functions in NativeScript

Tags: ios, nativescript

A plugin that I developed, https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-screen-orientation , breaks on 1.7.1 and above versions of tns-core-modules for iOS, while it works completely fine on 1.5.1, (it took me a day to find out tns-core-modules upgrades were breaking it) , this functionality is simply useful in many scenarios. I am essentially modifying the prototype chain native functions supportedInterfaceOrientations and preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation in the plugin for visibleViewController and UINavigationController, replacing them with required ones, however,I am getting this warning  :"Attempt to dismiss from view controller  while a presentation or dismiss is in progress", after which the screen goes blank in 1.7.1.Is there a separate way to modify prototype functions ? Are there any new abstractions introduced to wrap around navigation controllers and view controllers?

Comment: Did you tried version 2.0.0 or 2.0.1, maybe it was a bug in 1.7.1?

Comment: Yes , problem with that too